# How to know what items are taken in 2 knapsack problem?

Tags: c#, algorithm, knapsack-problem

This function takes:

1. **car1_laod**: KnapSack1 size.
2. **car2_load**: KnapSack2 size.
3. **N**: Number of items in the shop.
4. **load**: an array that carries the weight of the items.
5. **price**: an array that carries the price of the items.
6. **car1_items**: List that contains which items I picked and put inside car1.
7. **car2_items**: List that contains which items I picked and put inside car2.

The Goal is to know the max profit that I can get by adding items to car1 & car2
items cannot be selected twice.

```
    public static int GetMaximumProfit(int car1_load, int car2_load, int N, 
     int[] loads, int[] prices, List<int> car1_items, List<int> car2_items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        int[,] dp = new int[car1_load+1, car2_load+1];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for (int ks1=car1_load;ks1>=0;ks1--)
            {
                for(int ks2 = car2_load;ks2>=0;ks2--)
                {
                    if (ks1 >= loads[i] && ks2 >= loads[i])
                    {
                        dp[ks1, ks2] = max(
                                       dp[ks1, ks2],
                                       dp[ks1 - loads[i], ks2] + prices[i],
                                       dp[ks1, ks2 - loads[i]] + prices[i]
                                        );
                    }
                    else if (ks1 >= loads[i])
                    {  
                        dp[ks1, ks2] = Math.Max(
                                       dp[ks1, ks2],
                                       dp[ks1 - loads[i], ks2] + prices[i]
                                        );
                    }
                    else if (ks2 >= loads[i])
                    {

                        dp[ks1, ks2] = Math.Max(
                                       dp[ks1, ks2],
                                       dp[ks1, ks2 - loads[i]] + prices[i]
                                        );
                    }

                }
            }



        }



        cout(dp);
        Console.WriteLine("Answer : " + dp[car1_load, car2_load]);

        return dp[car1_load,car2_load];
    }
```

Example:

**Input:**

N = 4, car1_load = 5, car2_load = 2

Loads[4] = {1,2,3,5}

prices[4]={20,10,15,25}

**Output:**

The items to be inserted in the lists are the indices [1-based] of products selected to be loaded in both cars

Profit = 45

Car1 items = [2, 3]

Car2 items = [ 1 ]

My output:

[Example output of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ai3b.png)

I calculated the max  profit.

The Problem is that I don't know how to backtrack on the dp array to know where the items came from.

Comment: You code is not correct.  Using for loops you will need a separate nested for loop for each item from 1 to N.  You only have three nested for loops so you can only handle N = 3.  This problem requires recursion to give correct answer.  Then you need to save into a List() object which items were put into the cart so you can get the items that gave maximum profit.

Comment: IMO, the code is correct. But it needs to be modified to backtrack the solution. Every time it find the maximum value for each state dp[ks1,ks2], record what item it takes and where the item is placed. Assume it was stored in two array, take[ks1,ks2] and place[ks1,ks2]. You can backtrack the solution with that arrays.

Comment: @jdweng in the  example i put the N is  equal to 4  and it calculates right results

Comment: Do you get correct results if N = 10?

Comment: @jdweng I haven't tested it yet but  I want to create a dp solution thought.

Comment: If your code isn't going t work with 10 why continue fixing code that is designed incorrectly?  First design code that will work with all conditions and give you the inputs that gave the max profit.  Your code does not work under all conditions and does not give you the inputs that gave the max profit.  Go back to the drawing board.  Do not spend any more time on a bad solution.

Comment: @jdweng This is very similar to [the regular dynamic programming solution to the knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem) - that only has 2 nested loops and it works for any number of items.

Comment: It would probably help if you post a [mcve]. That is: include a short Main method showing how your method is called for the example. That would make it easier to test any potential answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another dimension to your array for the item index, similar to [the dynamic programming solution to the regular knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem) (you *may* be able to calculate it without this, but at the very least it's going to be more complex).

I'll leave the specifics to you, but that will give you something like this:

```
dp[i, ks1, ks2] = max(
    dp[i-1, ks1, ks2],
    dp[i-1, ks1 - loads[i], ks2] + prices[i],
    dp[i-1, ks1, ks2 - loads[i]] + prices[i]
);
```

Now you need to start at the end and repeatedly figure out which one of the above values was the maximum and continuing with that value.

This can be done by just checking whether the left-hand side is equal to any of the values on the right-hand side.

```
int ks1 = car1_load, ks2 = car2_load;
for (i = N; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (ks1 >= loads[i] && dp[i, ks1, ks2] == dp[i-1, ks1 - loads[i], ks2] + prices[i])
    {
        // Add i to car 1
        ks1 -= loads[i];
    }
    else if (ks2 >= loads[i] && dp[i, ks1, ks2] == dp[i-1, ks1, ks2 - loads[i]] + prices[i])
    {
        // Add i to car 2
        ks2 -= loads[i];
    }
    // if it's equal to dp[i-1, ks1, ks2], we don't need to do anything
}
```

The code may look a bit different than this, depending on how you actually changed your code to add the item index as an array dimension.